# Flowchart Quiz Library

Tags: php, jquery, logic

I have a friend who's working at a newspaper and has been given a big flow-chart for a sort of "Which of these are you?"-type online quiz. You know the type -- "Which type of athlete are you?", "Which Television Show X character are you?", etc.

Essentially Question A forks to two options, each of those options forks to another question with N options, each of which forks to another question with another arbitrary number of options, and so on, with the user eventually reaching an end-point. You might reach a "You are $this" response after 1 fork, or it might take 5. No question is used more than once.

I'm really quite curious what'd be the best way to do this. It could probably be done in ~1000 lines with a bunch of nested functions, but I get the feeling my lack of Computer Science education is failing me at this point. Alternatively, is there a library somewhere that'd be good for this, or is this simply a question of writing a bunch of code?

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: By the way, I'm curious about this project. How would you want to display it? Is it going to be a page by page question? or a tree like structure where you reveal all the branches each answers?

Comment: It'd be more of a paged thing. I have no time at the moment, but I'll go through your answer again in a bit. Thanks for it, by the way -- some nice detail there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only one Final Conclusion in the flowchart quiz, then the problem is comparable to **a 20Q Game**, **Category Page Arrangement**, or an **Org Chart**.

It may involve 3 columns: *Child Question(s)*, *Parent Question(s)*, and the *List Of Answers*.

- A *Child Question* acts like a *Parent Question* where there are other Nodes under it,
- A *Final Conclusion* acts like a *Child Question* (without any other Nodes, but just the Conclusion)
- The *List Of Answers* leads to the next Child Questions or Final Conclusion.

If the Final Question is asked, either it goes to the *Final Conclusion* (and ends) or it goes back to a certain *Parent Question* (to loop).

Hope it makes sense.

[image]

Comment: That makes sense -- have all the questions and answers stored as strings somewhere and then just reference them in the logic. Still seems really logically verbose, though. Option 2 doesn't work, there are a solid 10 results, which makes it difficult to abstract in that sense. Like, it makes sense and that's how I'd do it if I was brought in at the conceptual phase, but the goal is to replicate the flownchart I was given.

Comment: What are the example results that you will get? Is it a full paragraph or is it a final individual character or word? I may have a hint of what this is all about.

Comment: It's just like a sentence. "Hey! You're totally option X!", etc.